# Toggle element data for element that I click on, not all elements

Tags: reactjs

I want to toggle data for specific element I click on. Whenever I try to display element data then all items are toggling which I do not want. How can I only toggle the item I click on?

```js
export default function App() {
  const [post, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName ] = useState('');
  const [displayId, setDisplayId] = useState(false);
  const getPosts = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        setPosts(res);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(name);
  }, [name]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      {post.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
        <p>{item.title}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setDisplayId(el => el = !el)}>Show ID</button>
        { displayId &&
          <p>{item.id}</p>
        }
        </div>
      ))}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happezn!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be able to show or hide each item of the array separately, so your state should reflect that - it should contain a value for each element of the array, instead of having just a single `displayId` boolean.

```
const [displayToggles, setDisplayToggles] = useState([]);
const getPosts = () => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setPosts(res);
      setDisplayToggles(res.map(() => false));
    });
};

// ...
{post.map((item, i) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
    <p>{item.title}</p>
    <button
        onClick={() => setDisplayToggles(displayToggles.map((bool, j) => j === i ? !bool : bool))}
    >Show ID</button>
    { displayToggles[i] &&
```

Also

```
useEffect(() => {
  getPosts();
}, []);
```

simplifies to

```
useEffect(getPosts, []);
```

```js
function App() {
  const [post, setPosts] = React.useState([]);
  const [name, setName ] = React.useState('');
const [displayToggles, setDisplayToggles] = React.useState([]);
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setPosts(res);
      setDisplayToggles(res.map(() => false));
    });
}, []);

  return post.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
        <p>{item.title}</p>
    <button
        onClick={() => setDisplayToggles(displayToggles.map((bool, j) => j === i ? !bool : bool))}
    >Show ID</button>
    { displayToggles[i] &&
          <p>{item.id}</p>
        }
        </div>
        ));
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: I am getting this error with your code `displayToggles.map is not a function`

Comment: Initialize it to an array, not a boolean

Comment: I changed it to an empty array, not sure why nothing is being toggled now when clicking the button

Comment: I just tried it in my code editor, it looks to work just fine

Comment: I've updated my code, can you check it?

Comment: Did you call `setDisplayToggles` after the API call?